# how to select neighbouring elements in a vector and put them into a list or matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a problem about how to select neighboring elements in a vector and put them into a list or matrix in R. 
For example:

```
vl <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I want to get the results like this:

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
```

The results can be in a list or matrix

I know we can use a loop to get results.Like this:

```
pl <- list()
k=0
for (p in 1: length(vl)) {
          k=k+1
          pl[[k]] <- sort(c(vl[p],vl[p+1]))}
```

But I have a big data. Using loop is relatively slow.
Is there any function to get results directly?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
matrix(c(vl[-length(vl)], vl[-1]), ncol = 2)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    4
[4,]    4    5
```

If you want to sort two columns rowwise, then you can use `pmin()` and `pmax()` which will be faster than using `apply(x, 1, sort)` with a large number of rows.

```
sapply(c(pmin, pmax), do.call, data.frame(vl[-length(vl)], vl[-1]))
```

Comment: Same method, but a little more direct: `cbind(vl[-length(vl)], vl[-1])`

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! "cbind" is very good method. However, I forgot to say that in each row the elements should be sorted. I'm sorry the example is not very clear. Another example is: vl <- c(2,5,3,1,6,4). The result should be like: 2,5 3,5 1,3 1,6 4,6. Many thanks!

Comment: @Freeego sort post-hoc.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Many thanks! The methods are very good!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `head` and `tail` to ignore the last and first element respectively.

```
data.frame(a = head(vl, -1), b = tail(vl, -1))

#  a b
#1 1 2
#2 2 3
#3 3 4
#4 4 5
```

---

**EDIT**

If the data needs to be sorted  we can use `apply` row-wise to sort it.

```
vl <- c(2,5,3,1,6,4)
t(apply(data.frame(a = head(vl, -1), b = tail(vl, -1)), 1, sort))


#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    5
#[2,]    3    5
#[3,]    1    3
#[4,]    1    6
#[5,]    4    6
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! However, I forgot to say that in each row the elements should be sorted. I'm sorry the example is not very clear. Another example is: vl <- c(2,5,3,1,6,4). The result should be like: 2,5 3,5 1,3 1,6 4,6.

Comment: @Freeego We can row-wise sort it using `apply`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be solved by applying the `sort()` function on a *rolling window* of length 2:

```
vl <- c(2,5,3,1,6,4)
zoo::rollapply(vl, 2L, sort)
```

which returns a matrix as requested:

> ```
>      [,1] [,2]
> [1,]    2    5
> [2,]    3    5
> [3,]    1    3
> [4,]    1    6
> [5,]    4    6
> ```

Note that the *modified* input vector `vl` is used which has been posted by the OP in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825105/how-to-select-neighbouring-elements-in-a-vector-and-put-them-into-a-list-or-matr/60826106#comment107616615_60825163) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825105/how-to-select-neighbouring-elements-in-a-vector-and-put-them-into-a-list-or-matr/60826106#comment107616629_60825252).

Besides `zoo`, there are also other packages which offer *rollapply* functions, e.g.,

```
t(rowr::rollApply(vl, sort, 2L, 2L))
```